# What is the correct way to separate columns of data coming from the database

Tags: csv

I am new to android development, I need help with separation columns in csv files.

I can already do the data is saved in the next row and column. But when I export the data, appear some commas and quotation marks (") in the first column and the last. So I had to put some empty columns so that the figures do not mix with these unwanted commas and quotation marks. But they keep coming, where am I doing wrong?
Below the code:

```js
if (listdata.size() > 1) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < listdata.size(); index++) {
                        person = (br.com.att.actoap.Adapter.Person) listdata.get(index);
                        
                        String arrStr5[] = {" ", ";" + "/" + ";" + ";" + person.getSampleN() + ";" + person.getPeso() + ";" + person.getFatc() + ";" + person.getFsMol() + ";" + person.getFaAci() + ";" + person.getVolum() + ";" + person.getResu() + ";" + ";" + "/" + ""};
                        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr5);
                    }
```

Follow the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnPpM.png

I don't want this commas, how i can do to remove this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Another classic example of how patching a problem instead of fixing it - could lead you *way* deeper into the rabbit hole...

Comment: @alfasin Thanks, if you could help me, how i can proceed?

Comment: You shouldn't "proceed", you should back up and find out why these  quotes, commas and slashes are being inserted into the db/csv-file and fix *that*.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  (Maybe if you actually showed us the problem data that would help.)

Comment: @HotLicks in line  String arrStr5[] you see something wrong?

Comment: Show us the data as written (and not a spreadsheet of it, but the raw data that a text editor would display).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that cvswrite is actually writing ONE column to the CVS file as a corrent CSV file, with commas ',' and doublequotes '"'.

But your version of Excel expects a "localised" variant of a CSV file (read broken) and expects semicolons ';' as the separator instead of commas.

Possible solutions are

1. Configure Excel to read real CSV files and use your library correctly.
2. Configure your library to export semicolon separated files
3. Use TAB separated files instead.